# Installing php code Download

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new here! I do not have much knowledge yet in php, I have a question in which I have tried to put a break.tv api in my configuration so that users can download mp4 from a youtube video.

I have the script in which it is only downloaded in mp3 but I wanted to make it so that it can download in mp4 as well.

In my vdl.php folder I have this:

```
<div class = "lr">

<? php include '../admin/config.php'; ?>

<? php echo $ down_ad_728; ?>

<? php
$ vid = $ _REQUEST ['v'];
echo

<p>

<iframe style = "width: 100%; height: 60px; border: 0; overflow: hidden;" scrolling = "no" src = "//www.youtubeinmp3.com/widget/button/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= '. $ vid.' '& color = 555555>';
exit ();
?>

</ div>
```

Api break.tv (here I want to put)

```
<iframe src = "//break.tv/widget/mp4/?link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM" width = "400" height = "170" scrolling = "no" style = "border: none;"> </ iframe>
```

Can you help me how can I do this? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the [API docs](http://break.tv/en/api) there is a section for MP4, it looks like this:

break.tv/widget/**mp4**/?link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?
 v=i62Zjga8JOM" width="400" height="170" scrolling="no" style="border:none;">

Comment: I have this in my setup  <div class="lr" >
 <?php
include '../admin/config.php';
?>
 <?php
echo $down_ad_728; ?>
 <?php
$vid = $_REQUEST['v'];
echo '
 <p>
  <iframe style="width:100%;height:60px;border:0;overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" src="//www.youtubeinmp3.com/widget/button/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $vid . '"&color=555555>';
exit();
?>
  </div>

Comment: I am new to php wanted to know how to enable this api in script

Comment: It looks like you are using a different source (youtubeinmp3 instead of break.tv) and the generic mp3 button.